# Calculate possible coordinates of Nodes

Tags: c#, algorithm, nodes

This might be a weird application.
The brief description of the problem is "How to get Absolute Coordination of nodes based on Relative Positions (distances) ?"

We have a number of Nodes (each with a unique ID) and a list specifying its Adjacent nodes and distance to each of them as Input.

The required output would be one possible way to lay out these nodes on a 2D Surface.

The resulting algorithm is going to be used in C#... So external .net libraries might help too.

It would be a great help if you could advise me an approach to do that.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: By a "2D surface" do you mean a plane or something more exotic like a sphere or torus? Also -- what do you mean by "adjacent" nodes? Does your assignment of distances to pairs of nodes satisfy the triangle inequality? Without some assumptions on the distances it isn't clear that there is a solution.

Comment: To add to my last comment -- if you have 4 nodes, each of which is of distance 1 from the other 3 (an assignment of distances which satisfies the triangle inequality) it is impossible to do what you want on a plane surface in Euclidean space. The last three points would have to be vertices of an equilateral triangle inscribed on the circle of radius 1 centered on the first point, but an equilateral triangle inscribed on a unit circle doesn't have edges of length 1.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The 2D Surface is just a simple Plane... XY axis with double cords. (Actually screen) The input is in such a way that ensures at least a solution and they satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: I think, it is a correct question. It has many solutions depending of the depth of insight in the problem, and that makes it even more interesting. +1

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is "planar graph embedding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have coordinates of at least three known points at start.

Way I. If the known points are adjacent, the process is simple - you loop all your points, looking for such, which have in their lists three known points. Use two of them to count two possible positions, then use the third to choose right or left variant. Repeat the loops until you have no new points during a loop.

*That simple algorithm has bad convergence - the errors are accumulating and far points could have bad coordinates. But as you have the coordinates integer, you can repair coords after each counting and have them good.*

Way II. If the known points are not adjacent to each other, the process is more complicated.

- Let's say, you have start known points A,B,C.
- Take A and some its adjacent point D. Place it somewhere at the correct distance from A.
- Find some point E adjacent to A and D. Choose any of two possible positions.
- Starting from A, D, E, use the way I.
- When you reach by distances the second start known point, let it be B, of course, it will be in bad place. Turn all the net you have built around A so, that B will get the correct coordinates. Continue the looping.
- When you will reach the last of the start known points, C, it will be set correct or not. If not, mirror the whole net relatively AB axis - the C will be set correctly. (If not, you have bad data). Continue the way I looping till the end.

Both these two ways work if you have long lists for all points. If points have only few distances given, the task becomes much, much more complicated.